# Is it possible to add a separator in a javafx choicebox in FXML?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, separator

This document describes how to add a separator to a javafx 2 choicebox by code:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/choice-box.htm

I would like to achieve the same using a FXML layout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import java.lang.*?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <ChoiceBox>
    <String fx:value="Item 1" />
    <String fx:value="Item 2" />
    <Separator />
    <String fx:value="Item 3" />
  </ChoiceBox>
</HBox>
```

Don't forget to import the correct Class. With importing the correct classpath you can include any class and try to display it, even your self-made. Just open the FXML in your SceneBuilder and use **Preview** to see it in action without building a custom fxml loader for it.

[image: seperated choices]

Comment: Is this possible without FXML?

Comment: sure, but this should be in another question since this is strictly related to using FXML to solve it

Comment: It turns out to be easy: `choiceBox.add(Separator())`. But of course the `ChoiceBox` generic must be `Object`.

Comment: using `javafx.scene.Node` should work as a generic.You could also use `javafx.scene.control.Control` depending on the situation. Check out the inheritence in the javadoch at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Separator.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Replace the "Items" with your own content. Also, take a look at the FXML reference found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) for more information on using FXML.

```
<ChoiceBox>
  <items>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
      <String fx:value="Item 1" />
      <String fx:value="Item 2" />
      <Separator fx:id="separator"/>
      <String fx:value="Item 3" />
    </FXCollections>
  </items>
</ChoiceBox>
```